# Facebook Places Integration

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm trying to integrate Fb places with my Iphone app, sending the coordinates in the header of this request : https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins. But I'm getting a blank response data. What might be the problem? is there any tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to pull the places you've checked into, you don't send the longitude and latitude.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins
```

To get a list of nearby places the user can check into:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=<latitude>,<longitude>&distance=1000
```

Your `POST` to check in somewhere must include an `id` from one of the places returned.

Full docs at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

Comment: suppose i want to publish a new place then wat do i have to do?

Comment: There's not currently a public API for doing so.